# '<' character in string ignores .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I want to replace a certain string that contains text between '<' and '>'.

The funny thing is that .replace() works fine on practically any text, but when '<' is included in the string, it doesn't return a filtered string.

Here's some simple code to test it:http://jsfiddle.net/gy0y90g5/

What I've tried:

text only:

```
var res = str.replace('bijgevoegd>', "");
```

regex:

```
var res = str.replace(/bijgevoegd>/g, "");
```

Because jsfiddle won't display anything that's between `< >` I've just added one '>' in the example.

Anyone knows whats up with this quircky behaviour?

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/gy0y90g5/2/), and you'll get answer of your question.

Comment: Wew love the quick comments! Thanks @Tushar ! Solved it right now :)

Answer (score -1):

I made this, i dont know if this is what you want, but here yo go!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>STACK OVERFLOW TESTS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph below:</p>

    <p id = 'text'>< Something ></p>

    <input type = 'button' id = 'button' value = 'CLICK ME!'></input>

    <script>
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', doTheMagic);

        function doTheMagic(){
            var paragraph = document.getElementById('text');
            paragraph.innerHTML = '< W3Schools >'

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```